# Know where request came from

Tags: php, html, forms

I have multiple pages, say:

- wedding catering
- party catering
- house warming catering
- ETC

**All pages use the same form**

[image]

When the form is submitted the user gets directed to thank you.php which does the processing mail the form etc.

**MY QUESTION**

**I would like to find out which page the submitted form came from, is there any simple way to do this?**

Comment: http referer header ?

Comment: add local storage variable on click of the link and set the page name or any flag.

Comment: Do you know $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] , I think you should google it and it will get you some idea.

Comment: @dhpratik I just learned something by asking this question which is the goal of the site is it not - to help, educate and learn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As frz3993 suggested, using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is one option; however, I'd use this more for finding out what other sites users came from. Since this is your own site and you have control over the form generation, I would definitely go with a hidden field or something similar rather than trusting the user's browser to tell you which page submitted the form.

Never trust the client! :)

Comment: There are a lot of reasons to when the referer would be empty. So a hidden field is better. Never trust a client, just look like you trust them :)

Comment: Exactly. While it's probably not *likely* that you'll get a lot of empty referrers, it's just not worth wondering about who wants what at some point down the road (especially if this is for lead generation!) when you can avoid that by setting the data yourself in the first place.

Comment: I think the hidden field is better aswell but it is going to require a lot of editing - would you mind explaining a bit more about ` $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ` where / how should it get implemented? Also most of my traffic comes from google adwords for what that is worth

Comment: $_SERVER is one of PHP's 'superglobals;' it's built from various places including the request that came in from the client. HTTP_REFERER is something PHP pulls from the request sent by the user's browser, which *usually* tells you what page they were on before they clicked a link or submitted a form that brought them to the current page (but not if they were on another page and entered/pasted the current URL into their browser). As rfz3993 stated, there are various reasons it can be empty or even wrong, so it's not something to depend on if you can reasonably avoid it.

Comment: If you mean the hidden field, you would add it on a per-page basis to your form, presumably by setting some sort of variable that's referenced in the shared form template, so on the pages that render the form. $_SERVER would be implemented on the thank-you.php page, since that's where the data is being sent, so the referrer should in theory be set to the page the user was on when they submitted the form.

$_SERVER: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 4):

The simplest ways are:

- use the referrer header (`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, with the typo missing `R`) or
- use a hidden form field that differs from one page to another.

Whichever you use, just check the value on the page that processes the submission and go from there.

Comment: I think the hidden form field is the simplest way to go but that means I will need to edit every form. Can you please explain a bit more on the `HTTP_REFERER` method and how / where I should implement it? Thank you very much

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee In the target page, check the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`; it will tell you which page the user was on when he or she submitted the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use here a hidden field for all different pages with all different values to trace the page.

for example you can use field name "came_from"

```
1.wedding catering
<input type="hidden" name="came_from" value="wedding catering">

2. party catering
<input type="hidden" name="came_from" value="party catering">
```

so on.